# What are `files`, `executables`, `test_files`, and `require_paths` in gemspec file?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, gemspecs

I am not clear on what certain specifications in the `.gemspec` file are doing. Specifically,

```
spec.files         = `git ls-files -z`.split("\x0")
spec.executables   = spec.files.grep(%r{^bin/}) { |f| File.basename(f) }
spec.test_files    = spec.files.grep(%r{^(test|spec|features)/})
spec.require_paths = ["lib"]
```

Can someone explain how these relate to the functionality of a Ruby Gem and why they are necessary?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[`executables`](http://guides.rubygems.org/specification-reference/#executables):

Executables included in the gem. For example, the rake gem has rake as an executable. These files must be executable Ruby files.

[`files`](http://guides.rubygems.org/specification-reference/#files):

Files included in the gem. These are the files that will be included in your gem when it is built.

[`require_paths`](http://guides.rubygems.org/specification-reference/#require_paths=):

Contains an `Array` of directories and files which should be added to the `$LOAD_PATH` on gem activation. By default it is `["lib"]`.

[`test_files`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/rubygems/rdoc/Gem/Specification.html#method-i-test_files-3D)

Test files included in the gem.

Comment: In ruby 2.2.0 there are no more `test_files`.